# Does reinstalling a new version of Xcode automatically overwrite the old?

Tags: xcode

Does reinstalling a new version of Xcode automatically overwrite the old?

e.g. I had xcode 3.2.5 and I downloaded and installed Xcode 3.2.6 (including ios).  Does the install overwrite and get rid of **all** the xcode 3.2.5 data (assuming it doesn't use any of it)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no.  It will overwrite files in `/Developer/usr`, `/Developer/Tools`, `/Developer/Library`, etc, but if a file already exists that the new Xcode install does not have an upgrade for, the installer wont touch it if it doesn't have to.  Personally, I have found that the best way to upgrade Xcode is the following:

1. Backup the working `/Developer` directory (where the "old" Xcode is installed)

   ```
   [ 15:30 jon@MacBookPro / ]$ sudo mv /Developer /Developer-3.2.5
   ```
2. Run the "new" Xcode installer using the default install location (`/Developer`).

This way you have everything from both and can merge the files you need.